# MySQL version of split_to_array or split_to_table?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, json, array, string-manipulation

PostgreSQL supports two [*String Functions*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), that are incredibly useful

- [`regexp_split_to_array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)
- [`regexp_split_to_table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

Both of these functions essentially take two strings, (a) a pattern and (b) an input string and return either an [`array[]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) or set of [row types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html).

This is great for problems [like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/202618/2639). MySQL has a JSON type, and version 8 even brings binary JSON. Does it support any string splitting into a [`JSON_ARRAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array) or the like. Or, is there an easy method to implement this?

Comment: Most probably not as MySQL does not have support for set returning functions (or arrays)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but it does support JSON which I name explicitly a suitable alternative.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - File a feature request at bugs.mysql.com .